# Как оптимизировать повторное использование шаблона ListCell в JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

В рамках упражнения "Приложение TODO List" хочу создать такой вот список карточек:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каждая карточка инициализируется таким образом:

```
public class TasksListController {

  private static class TaskCell extends ListCell<ObservableTask> {

    @FXML private HBox rootElement;
    @FXML private Label titleLabel;
    @FXML private Label noteLabel;

    public TaskCell() {
      this.loadFXML();
    }


    private void loadFXML() {
      try {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/Presenter/Components/TaskList/TaskCard.fxml"));
        loader.setController(this);
        loader.load();
      } catch (IOException exception) {
        System.out.println("Failed to load 'TaskCard.fxml' component:\n" + exception.getMessage());
      }
    }


    @Override
    public void updateItem(ObservableTask observableTask, boolean doesNotRepresentAnyDomainData) {

      super.updateItem(observableTask, doesNotRepresentAnyDomainData);

      if (doesNotRepresentAnyDomainData) {
        return;
      }

      this.setGraphic(this.rootElement);

      this.titleLabel.setText(observableTask.getTitle());

      if (observableTask.getNote() != null) {
        this.noteLabel.setText(observableTask.getNote());
      }
    }
  }

  // ...
}
```

При создании каждой карточки происходит чтение файла `TaskCard.fxml`, а такое расточительное использование вычислительных ресурсов недопустимо. Но как это можно оптимизировать?

### Мои размышления

Концептуально, решение такое:

1. Читаем FXML-файл один раз и сохраняем его в статическое полe
2. Для каждой `ListCell` делаем копию этого файла.
3. Добиться того, чтобы изменения данных таска отражались только на индивидуальной копии FXML-шаблона.

При реализации образуются следующие вопросы:

1. Насколько мне известно, `getResource` возвращает URL. Но происходит ли при этом чтение файла? Если да, то это неочевидно из названия метода, но если нет, то URL шаблона `TaskCard.fxml` можно смело выносить в статическое поле.
2. Может ли быть инстанс `FXMLLoader` один на все карточки? Наверное нет, потому что мы будем вызывать `loader.setController(this);` при создании каждой `ListCell`.
3. Не совсем понятно, в какой момент происходит чтение файла. Скорее всего, это `loader.load();`. Но что он возвращает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

от `new FXMLLoader()` не получится никуда уйти, т.к. он хранит в себе иерархию и биндинги конкретного элемента. Кстати код можно немного улучшить, `loader.load()` возвращает корневой элемент, который можно вставить в `setGraphic()`.

Чтение файла происходит в методе `load()`, он из `InputStream` забирает данные. Т.к. ресурсные данные не лежат в памяти, то каждый раз происходит чтение из диска. Логично, что вместо файла можно подставить свой поток данных, например:

```
private static byte[] xml;

public TaskCell() {
  final FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();

  try {
    if(xml == null) {
      xml = getClass()
              .getResource("/Presenter/Components/TaskList/TaskCard.fxml")
              .openStream()
              .readAllBytes();
    }

    loader.setController(this);
    rootElement = loader.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml));
  } catch (IOException exception) {
    System.out.println("Failed to load 'TaskCard.fxml' component:\n" + exception.getMessage());
  }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ!